# UITableView with NSLayoutConstraint returns null with runtime crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

I have 2 View Controllers - TableContainer and TableView. TableView is `UIViewController` subclass that conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` and Delegate. a `UITableView` is a property in the TableView controller.

I init 5 TableView controllers in TableContainer and add the tableView properties as subviews of the main TableContainer view.

I then layout with `NSLayoutConstraint` to fit the 5 tableViews in the TableContainer view. I get this crash

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint must contain a first layout item'

I've logged it and the reason is that the tableView property is null. However, I've run the same exact code with the TableView controller not as a subclassed `UIViewController` but as an actual UITableViewController and it works fine.

Code follows
TableView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
```

TableView.m (leaving out delegate and datasource methods because I've tested and those work fine)

```
@interface TableView ()

@end

@implementation TableView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    [self.tableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

}
```

TableContainer.h

```
@interface TableContainer : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) TableView *tvVC1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TableView *tvVC2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TableView *tvVC3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TableView *tvVC4;
@property (strong, nonatomic) TableView *tvVC5;

@end
```

TableContainer.m (omitting code for constraints for tvVC's 2-5 as they are the same as the one for tvVC1.)

```
@implementation TableContainer

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tvVC1 = [[TableView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tvVC1.tableView];

    self.tvVC2 = [[TableView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tvVC2.tableView];

    self.tvVC3 = [[TableView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tvVC3.tableView];

    self.tvVC4 = [[TableView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tvVC4.tableView];

    self.tvVC5 = [[TableView alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tvVC5.tableView];

}


-(void)viewDidAppear{

        UILayoutGuide *layoutGuide = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide;


        self.tvVC1.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
        NSLayoutConstraint *vc1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tvVC1.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.2f constant:0.0f];
        vc1.active = TRUE;
        [self.tvVC1.tableView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:layoutGuide.leadingAnchor].active = TRUE;
        [self.tvVC1.tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:layoutGuide.topAnchor].active = TRUE;
        [self.tvVC1.tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:layoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't caused the child table view controllers to load/create their views. You need to access the `view` property, not just the `tableView` property, of each child view controller to make that happen.

Comment: So what should I do exactly? add the tableView to the view and then add that to the Container view?

Comment: You should be adding the `view` of each child view controller to your container view controller's view. You should also add each child view controller as a child of your container view controller. Read [“Implementing a Custom Container View Controller” in the *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1).